# Arch Linux: USB mouse fails after an hour of running

Tags: linux, mouse, xorg, hardware-failure, arch-linux

I have just installed Arch Linux with kernel version 3.9.5-1. While running xorg (in particular, XMonad), my Microsoft optical USB mouse fails (stops sending movements) after a length of time, *every time* I run my computer. When I look at the underside, the light is still on, but it is significantly dimmer. The problem is not solved by restarting xorg, but rebooting the computer temporarily fixes the problem.

Only a couple of days ago, I had been running both Windows 7 and a previous version of Arch with no problems regarding the mouse at all, so I think that the mouse itself is still fully working. Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I can solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Really just a shot in the dark but your mouse might be recognized as a touchpad and if you don't have "Disable touchpad while typing" unchecked in the system settings it may fail to enable the mouse again after you were typing.

Answer (score 2):

> **UPDATE:** I have written an [article about USB autosuspend issues](http://hamwaves.com/usb.autosuspend/en/index.html) with GNU/Linux. Check this out for a more elegant solution.

I had a similar issue with a *Microsoft Wheel Mouse Optical USB and PS/2 Compatible* since upgrading a [Linux Mint Debian Edition](http://www.linuxmint.com/download_lmde.php) system to kernel `3.10-2-amd64`. The culprit is an inappropriate autosuspend by the kernel's [USB power management](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/usb/power-management.txt). In Debian, this is compiled as the `usbcore` module into the kernel.

You can resolve this permanently by issuing at the command line:

```
sudo echo "options usbcore autosuspend=-1" > /etc/modprobe.d/disable-usb-autosuspend.conf
```

Some kernels might require `autosuspend=0`, though.

If your system uses `initrd` (most probably do), then rebuild the `initrd` for your kernel.

For example:

```
uname -r
sudo dpkg-reconfigure linux-image-3.10-2-amd64
```

Reboot and check with:

```
cat /sys/module/usbcore/parameters/autosuspend
```

which should yield `-1` now.